# MySQL GROUP BY grouping by lowest field value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch the lowest price per day per hotel, I get multiple results.
I first try to fetch the lowest amount with the MIN() function, then inner join.
When i later try to group by outside the subquery, it just groups by the lowest id.
The SQL itself:

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.amount, mt.fk_hotel, mt.start_date   
FROM price mt 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT price.id, MIN(price.amount) minAmount
    FROM price
    WHERE 1=1 AND price.start_date >= '2014-10-08' AND price.start_date <= '2014-10-10' AND price.active = 1 AND price.max_people = 2
    GROUP BY id
) t 
ON mt.id = t.id AND mt.amount = t.minAmount
ORDER BY mt.fk_hotel, mt.amount;
```

And the results looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/63mg3b2j/

I want to group by the start date and fk_hotel so that it groups by the lowest amount value, can anybody help me? Am I being clear?

Edit: I also need a field fk_room from the corresponding row, so i can inner join

Comment: If you have a problem with SQL, then an SQLFIDDLE would probably be more useful than a JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all get a table with minimum value in top row using `ORDER BY` and then `GROUP BY` for your required result

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.amount, mt.fk_hotel, mt.start_date   
FROM 
   (SELECT id, amount, fk_hotel, start_date
    FROM price
    WHERE start_date >= '2014-10-08' AND start_date <= '2014-10-10' 
    AND active = 1 AND max_people = 2
    ORDER BY amount DESC) AS mt
GROUP BY mt.id
```

Comment: Didin't work. I got 4 result for fk_hotel = 1 and start_date = 2014-10-08. And the id's and amounts didn't reflect the right row in DB (For example id 223 amount is supposed to be 195, but i got 175).

Comment: please add a sqlfiddle not jsfiddle, moroever please provide a schema of your db. I would be able to help you for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(mt.amount) AS min_amount, mt.fk_hotel, mt.start_date 
FROM price mt 
WHERE 
    mt.active = 1 AND 
    mt.max_people = 2 AND
    mt.start_date >= '2014-10-08' AND mt.start_date <= '2014-10-10'
GROUP BY mt.fk_hotel, mt.start_date 
ORDER BY mt.fk_hotel, min_amount;
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but the problem is with getting the corresponding fields that might also be useful on that row. So let's say there's a fk_roomtype field, if i add that to the select fields, it will fetch the first result value in DB, not the corresponding one to that specific amount. I want to get the fk_roomtype to do a inner join on another table. I guess that needs a subquery? How can this query be enhanced?

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to still go with a subquery, cause i needed some additional foreign key fields from the corresponding row to inner join some other stuff. It isn't a great solution, cause it fetches too much stuff, the rest is filtered out programmatically.

The most annoying thing here, when I try to use MIN() or MAX() function and get the appropriate fields to that row, it fetches the first results from the DB, which are incorrect and so i have to use a subquery to inner join to get the other fields, I can use grouping, but I had too many fields to group. Maybe I'm missing something. The amount of data doesn't grow in time, so I guess it works for me. So this is the final SQL i came up with, for future reference..

```
SELECT mt.*, roomtype.name roomname, hotel.name hotelname 
FROM booking.price mt 
INNER JOIN roomtype ON roomtype.id = mt.fk_roomtype 
INNER JOIN hotel ON hotel.id = mt.fk_hotel 
INNER JOIN(             
    SELECT price.id, MIN(price.amount) minAmount 
    FROM booking.price WHERE 1=1 AND price.start_date >= '2014-10-22' AND price.start_date <= '2014-10-31' AND price.max_people = 2 AND price.active = 1 
    GROUP BY id
) t 
ON mt.id = t.id AND mt.amount = t.minAmount  
ORDER BY mt.start_date, mt.amount
```